# Selenium and Private Proxies

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to know how to add private proxies to my Selenium tests specifically when using Firefox Driver.

I know there is a similar question on SO which suggested to use BrowserMob however I want to be able to do it without downloading any external applications.

Is there a way to do it directly ? I'm talking about using private proxies which require authentication.

I have read hundreds of SO posts but none provided a solution.. I am using Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
import org.openqa.selenium.Proxy.ProxyType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class WebdriverUsingProxy {

    private List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        urlList.add("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
        urlList.add("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void passTraffixThroughProxyTest() {
        String httpProxy = "192.168.1.101:8080";
        String sslProxy = "192.168.1.101:8080";
        String ftpProxy = "192.168.1.101:8080";

        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        addProxyCapabilities(capability, httpProxy, sslProxy, ftpProxy);

        for (String url : urlList){
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capability);
            driver.get(url);
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    public static DesiredCapabilities addProxyCapabilities(DesiredCapabilities capability, String httpProxy, String sslProxy,
            String ftpProxy) {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.setProxyType(ProxyType.MANUAL);
        proxy.setHttpProxy(httpProxy);
        proxy.setSslProxy(sslProxy);
        proxy.setFtpProxy(ftpProxy);

        capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
        capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        return capability;
    }
}
```

The proxy type is manual and I’ve set the HTTP, SSL and FTP proxy to 192.168.1.101:8080. This is done using the Proxy object and setting the desired capability. You can pass it as variable though.